# Почему ts пишет что реализация фуцнкции не совпадает с ее типом?

Tags: typescript

Описал тип функции как написано в документации
[typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures)

При написании реализации функции TS почему то пишет что типы не совпадают.
Скажите пожалуйста - где я ошибся ?

```
type PropertyFuncType = {
  (a: number): number;
  apply(this: Function, thisArg: any, argArray?: any): any;
};
// type PropertyFuncType = Function;

function Method2(): MethodDecorator {
  return <PropertyFuncType>(
    target: Object,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    propertyDescriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<PropertyFuncType>
  ) => {
    const oldValue: PropertyFuncType = propertyDescriptor.value!;

// Type '(a: number) => number' is not assignable to type 'PropertyFuncType'.
//  'PropertyFuncType' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '(a: number) => number'.(2322)
// сам тип функции я описал как в документации:
// https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures

    propertyDescriptor.value = function (a: number): number {

      // Подскажите пожалуйста, почему TS пишет что типы не совпадают ? 
      // Property 'apply' does not exist on type 'PropertyFuncType' - я же apply сам в тип записал ?
      const result: number = oldValue.apply(this, a);

      return result * 10;
    };
  };
}
```

Ссылка на playground:
[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nUAxArgOwMYBVzQC8UA3gFBRQAUAhgFxSboC2ARhHAJQNNscDcFKDTBgANiCrAAFgEsAzgww5gshJgA0UGQoCCcAOYMamEFpqH9cGiAD8x092GnBAX0EB6D9oKxEyNCw8X2JlbFV1QTIAMyCIzCgAWQgZBAATACYqJ2TUtIARCGwEa2AS0iE4FPQ4BIAeeCQOQJx8SAA+KiFKYAsDFIYAeVYAKyLgDW6oMH9mkABpCBAGeWA4WUwDKAAfKHkQNgQxScpKGaaUEEL5bHWwMrgGNog0xoCriBu7h4bZy7Dnu0hJwoIR2hVTlBiphVlAjmkAGo0MToCAMN5zAEhaZ-UDXW6ye4lAB0ADdkaiAIRRLxQZ5QADktB4LHYXFB4N4bIZUAUjAQwGE8nksgMmBorDE0DKPkgjIx-yCzwZxLItPluJAWMgPOK6DEaSg7F5MN6mFUNGALygAHdZDJnMI4Kx7dY4CBZdAbXJsNIoQh9YbjVgqmJLdaZUz6IxWRwQWCY3w4CqqBkAMwZDKcNXeQCCIIAGEEAPCBQQBCIIAOEEA-CBQQAiIIBhEEAvCCALhBAGIgZbLUEA8iBQQB8IBWywXANwgUEb+cbUEATCBQQAsIN3G7XC4BWEHrJfzrbLdBzUGkwGAYEUXhth+JoEgX0JwDDm2JJQMHjSCGw8g80hMaVYCAQAGsPBkPLEVGoMLEtuzBiAAxNgyJiAAtCKYqWjUnxkFM5zvPi3wkuSKJEFA-7hIB1DRlycYskmFRTJQtKAPgg3ZTrmI6AGwgZYlguUAVt2DH5gOtaAJwguYrlo7GAOIgC6FrWdIAMpsWWgASIAuJZQEJJbdqWlaANIgUD1qxubduOFb5lO+aAHIgCm2FAFFQLSCqgIyIjiCAPL3p8-KChAAAeCiCuonoahcLTBDqUDQZ2UAMaxdkSFABbFpO5ZVoA7CD5n2g5QLYFnQrCVTyPqwCkWyoJwgaSLYcSEWSDo8jmJwUSQpQVTADUCRZTlUAAFRQAAjAADIIkLuEI-WuGQQA)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132060/discussion-between-gayrat-vlasov-and-grundy)

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте использовать следующий код

> Ссылка на пример [доступна в gist](https://gist.github.com/tripolskypetr/7cbfce68e82a24e4166387f67ff4b33f)

```
import 'reflect-metadata';

function Method2(): MethodDecorator {
  return function (target, propertyKey): PropertyDescriptor {
    const descriptor = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, propertyKey)!;
    return {
      ...descriptor,
      value() {
        return descriptor.value?.apply(target, arguments) * 10;
      },
    };
  };
}

class Test {
  @Method2()
  applyTest() {
    return 10;
  }
}

const test = new Test();
const result1 = test.applyTest();
console.log(result1);
```